# Sort each dictionary then pivot it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with dictionaries, keys of dictionaries are randomly ordered, dictionaries may contain different amount of keys (starting from 0)
My goal is to sort keys in each row and then pivot them, to make keys column headers and store its` values accordingly.

I made my way from raw data and unpacking from json to writing it into df, and now I`m stuck

A few examples:

```
{'key_b': 40, 'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 15, 'key_h': 11, 'key_f': 15, 'key_a': 273, 'key_c': 9}

{'key_c': 10, 'key_a': 286, 'key_b': 42}

{'key_f': 1}

{'key_g': 'trial', 'key_i': 1}

{'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 3, 'key_h': 2, 'key_i': 1, 'key_c': 11, 'key_b': 47, 'key_a': 325, 'key_g': 'premium'}

{'key_g': 'trial'}
```

And I want it to have the next appearance:

```
key_a   key_b   key_c   key_d   key_e   key_f   key_g   key_h   key_i
273     40      null    1
325     42      9       null     etc
286     41      9       10`
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting and using pandas.pivot_table() after creating dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Dict Column": [
    
 {'key_b': 40, 'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 15, 'key_h': 11, 'key_f': 15, 'key_a': 273, 'key_c': 9},

{'key_c': 10, 'key_a': 286, 'key_b': 42},

{'key_f': 1},

{'key_g': 'trial', 'key_i': 1},

{'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 3, 'key_h': 2, 'key_i': 1, 'key_c': 11, 'key_b': 47, 'key_a': 325, 'key_g': 'premium'},

{'key_g': 'trial'}
    ]})

df = pd.json_normalize(df['Dict Column'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
       key_b  key_d  key_e  key_h  key_f  key_a  key_c    key_g  key_i
0   40.0    1.0   15.0   11.0   15.0  273.0    9.0      NaN    NaN
1   42.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  286.0   10.0      NaN    NaN
2    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN
3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    trial    1.0
4   47.0    1.0    3.0    2.0    NaN  325.0   11.0  premium    1.0
5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    trial    NaN
```

Comment: Awesome :)

result = result.reindex(sorted(result.columns), axis = 1)

For sorting them in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

1. Create the dataframe from the dictionaries (I hope you have a column with dictionaries. You can convert the column into a list of dictionaries and then create a dataframe).
2. Drop duplicates
3. Sort them

   ```
   dict1 = {'key_b': 40, 'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 15, 'key_h': 11, 'key_f': 15, 'key_a': 273, 'key_c': 9}
   dict2 = {'key_c': 10, 'key_a': 286, 'key_b': 42}
   dict3 = {'key_f': 1}
   dict4 = {'key_g': 'trial', 'key_i': 1}
   dict5 = {'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 3, 'key_h': 2, 'key_i': 1, 'key_c': 11, 'key_b': 47, 'key_a': 325, 'key_g': 'premium'}
   dict6 = {'key_g': 'trial'}

   lis = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5, dict6]
   df = pd.DataFrame()
   result = pd.DataFrame()
   for i in range(len(lis)-1):
       df = pd.DataFrame(data = lis[i], index = range(len(lis[i]))).drop_duplicates().append(pd.DataFrame(data = lis[i+1], index = range(len(lis[i+1]))).drop_duplicates())
       result = result.append(df)
   result = result.drop_duplicates()
   result = result.reindex(sorted(result.columns), axis = 1)
   result
   ```

This will give the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cause there is no additional info in your question, how the data frame looks like - I start in my example with a series of the data frame that contains your dicts to explain the steps. See full example at the end.

```
pd.DataFrame([dict(sorted(x.items())) for x in pd.Series(d)])
```

1. Pick your Series

   ```
   pd.Series(d)
   ```
2. Iterate and sort it:

   ```
   [dict(sorted(x.items())) for x in pd.Series(d)]
   ```
3. Create a data frame

   ```
   pd.DataFrame([dict(sorted(x.items())) for x in pd.Series(d)])
   ```

Additionally you would concat it to your original data Frame.

```
pd.concat([ORIGINAL_DF, NEW_DF], axis=1)
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{'key_b': 40, 'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 15, 'key_h': 11, 'key_f': 15, 'key_a': 273, 'key_c': 9},
     {'key_c': 10, 'key_a': 286, 'key_b': 42},
     {'key_f': 1},
     {'key_g': 'trial', 'key_i': 1},
     {'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 3, 'key_h': 2, 'key_i': 1, 'key_c': 11, 'key_b': 47, 'key_a': 325, 'key_g': 'premium'},
     {'key_g': 'trial'}]

pd.DataFrame([dict(sorted(x.items())) for x in pd.Series(d)])
```

#### Outpout

| key_a | key_b | key_c | key_d | key_e | key_f | key_h | key_g | key_i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 273.0 | 40.0 | 9.0 | 1.0 | 15.0 | 15.0 | 11.0 |  |  |
| 286.0 | 42.0 | 10.0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | 1.0 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | trial | 1.0 |
| 325.0 | 47.0 | 11.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |  | 2.0 | premium | 1.0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | trial |  |

#### Example (incl. data frame)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'user_properties':[{'key_b': 40, 'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 15, 'key_h': 11, 'key_f': 15, 'key_a': 273, 'key_c': 9},
            {'key_c': 10, 'key_a': 286, 'key_b': 42},
            {'key_f': 1},
            {'key_g': 'trial', 'key_i': 1},
            {'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 3, 'key_h': 2, 'key_i': 1, 'key_c': 11, 'key_b': 47, 'key_a': 325, 'key_g': 'premium'},
            {'key_g': 'trial'}
        ]
    }
)

pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([dict(sorted(x.items())) for x in df.user_properties])], axis=1)
```

| col1 | user_properties | key_a | key_b | key_c | key_d | key_e | key_f | key_h | key_g | key_i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {'key_b': 40, 'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 15, 'key_h': 11, 'key_f': 15, 'key_a': 273, 'key_c': 9} | 273.0 | 40.0 | 9.0 | 1.0 | 15.0 | 15.0 | 11.0 |  |  |
| 2 | {'key_c': 10, 'key_a': 286, 'key_b': 42} | 286.0 | 42.0 | 10.0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | {'key_f': 1} |  |  |  |  |  | 1.0 |  |  |  |
| 4 | {'key_g': 'trial', 'key_i': 1} |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | trial | 1.0 |
| 5 | {'key_d': 1, 'key_e': 3, 'key_h': 2, 'key_i': 1, 'key_c': 11, 'key_b': 47, 'key_a': 325, 'key_g': 'premium'} | 325.0 | 47.0 | 11.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |  | 2.0 | premium | 1.0 |
| 6 | {'key_g': 'trial'} |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | trial |  |

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault that I haven't clarified well the problem, just my beginning at StackOverflow. Also, I can t reveal the full data I m working with.

I've got about 30 columns in my df, so I need to pick one, sort keys, and then pivot it. Could you please explain how can I pick a column named `user_properties` and do all the following operations I need?

Comment: Take a look at the last example, just changed the name of column to user_properties. `pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([dict(sorted(x.items())) for x in df.user_properties])], axis=1)`